# Can I pass a Breeze.js query via Node.js and Edge.js to .NET?

Tags: node.js, nhibernate, breeze, edgejs

In my current project we are using Angular with a Node.js backend. The Node.js backend talks via Edge.js to our .NET assemblies, which, in turn, connect via NHibernate to our database.

Is there any possibility to route the Breeze.js calls directly to a service on the .NET side that acts kind of like a WebAPI controller?

I cannot get rid of Node.js and would like to spare myself the cumbersome task of manually creating filtering, paging, and sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to use breezejs.
What I did though was using kendo ui datasources. I created a custom datasource that sent the query filters (a triple of "column", "operation", "value") as JSON to my web service where I went through all the deserialized triples and created a Linq-Query from scratch.

It is not ODATA, but it works like a charm and enabled me to map queries that were based on a client model (DTOs) to our domain model.